# Mark esbuild as external dependency in SvelteKit

Tags: vercel, vite, sveltekit, esbuild

I'm working on a SvelteKit application and I'm using esbuild on an API endpoint to transform code that gets POSTed.

I'm importing transformSync from esbuild to do this:

`import { transformSync } from 'esbuild';`

This is all working fine both when running the dev server and also when building and running the production preview locally with SvelteKit. However, when I push to production (on Vercel, using the vercel adapter), I'm running into the following error:

```
Error: The esbuild JavaScript API cannot be bundled. Please mark the "esbuild" package as external so it's not included in the bundle.
More information: The file containing the code for esbuild's JavaScript API (/var/task/index.js) does not appear to be inside the esbuild package on the file system, which usually means that the esbuild package was bundled into another file. This is problematic because the API needs to run a binary executable inside the esbuild package which is located using a relative path from the API code to the executable. If the esbuild package is bundled, the relative path will be incorrect and the executable won't be found.
```

I've tried adding the following to my SvelteKit Vite config:

```
vite: {
    ssr: {
        external: ['esbuild']
    }
}
```

and:

```
vite: {
    optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ['esbuild']
    }
}
```

Neither worked.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @Alex No I ended up moving the transpilation to an external API endpoint and calling that API from the SvelteKit app instead. Now using @swc/core instead of esbuild as well (although I can't now remember why I chose that over esbuild).